# Error running Blazor WebAssembly BECanvas on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, blazor-webassembly

Running Blazor WebAssembly app. Using BECanvas test code from the github page, https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Canvas, app works fine on localhost, but when I publish to azure, everything works except BECanvas. Getting error Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'BlazorExtensions.Canvas2d.add' ('BlazorExtensions' was undefined). I'm a bit lost on what to do next.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except I even get the `'BlazorExtensions' was undefined` error when debugging on localhost using IIS. Have you managed to find a solution or any more information?

Comment: That's a JavaScript error. Did you load the package's Javascript files in your `index.html` ?